# Different ways to define UI elements in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-directive

When using ionic framework for building apps, there are two ways how UI elements can be defined:

using `div` tags:

```
<div class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
  ...
</div>
```

using directives:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
  ...
</ion-header-bar>
```

In the [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#header), the first variant (using `div`) is used. But in a course I was watching, the second one was used (and it seemed cleaner to me).

What are the differences between the two ways shown above? Is there a preferred or recommended way of defining UI elements?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use Directives instead of Div if you need to access to corresponding APIs. For example for a list : http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionList/ 
Using the directive will allow you to use APIs options.

BUT, if you just want a beautiful UI, and you don't need APIs, you can use div which will render templates fastly.

Answer (score 1):

ion-header-bar tag is just Directive written by ionic with some fantastic attribute which you will not get in div tag

attribute like :

**align-title**

**no-tap-scroll**

this both comes with ion-header-bar tag so if you want to perform any action on the view so u can use ion tag or only for view purpose you can use div tag.